# Memory Error when running my C++ code w/ Rcpp/RcppArmadillo : Can't identify exactly what is wrong after debugging with valgrind

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I've just started studying Rcpp and I'm trying to implement PRIM's algorithm. After tons of help and some reading, I have a version that works well, except for simulated data with n=50 or n=1050 (w/ seed 1984).

My RStudio throws the "R session Aborted" screen. From the terminal (I'm using Linux Mint 18.3) I get

> **** Error in `/usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x00000000039f8690 ***

After seeking for how to debug my compiled code, I've found:

- some material form @Dirk Eddelbuettel explaining about gdb:
  http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/papers/rcpp_uzuerich_2015_part5_packaging.pdf
- some material from @Kevin Ushey explaining about valgrind:
  http://kevinushey.github.io/blog/2015/04/05/debugging-with-valgrind/

I've also read about lldb, but decided to go with valgrind.

I've prepared a *cod_valgrind_test.R* file in which I generate data and compile my C++ files. All those files are in my github repo (https://github.com/allanvc/test), but I decided to reproduce the code of the problematic file (prim_cpp_bug.cpp) here:

```
#include <iostream>
//#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

//using namespace Rcpp;
//using namespace arma;
using namespace std;


// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]


// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List prim_cpp(arma::mat x)
{


    int V = x.n_cols;

    arma::uvec parent(V);
    parent.at(0) = 0;

    double max_value = x.max()+1;

    int v = 0;

    int idxmin_geral = 0;

    arma::uvec min_subnot;

    arma::mat new_m;

    arma::uvec from(V-1);
    //from.at(0) = 0;

    arma::uvec to(V-1);



    for(int i=0; i < V; i++)
    {
        // "deleting" the row for current vertex by setting the maximum to all entries in this row
        x.row(v).fill(max_value); // better than using loop

        // insert object x.col(v) at col i of new_m matrix
        new_m.insert_cols(i,x.col(v)); //see arma.sourceforge.net 

        //cout << new_m << endl;

        // obtain the minimum index from the selected columns
        idxmin_geral = new_m.index_min();

        // obtain the subscript notation from index based on reduced dimensions ***
        min_subnot = arma::ind2sub(arma::size(new_m.n_rows, new_m.n_cols),
                                    idxmin_geral);
        // *** adapted from @coatless
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045895/how-to-find-the-index-of-the-minimum-value-between-two-specific-columns-of-a-mat                                    

        v = min_subnot.at(0);
        parent.at(i+1) = v; // -----> !! this is line 61 <-----

        to.at(i) = min_subnot.at(0); // -----> !! this is line 63 <-----
        from.at(i) = parent.at(min_subnot.at(1)); // -----> !! this is line 64 <-----

        // "deleting" the row for current vertex by setting maximum to all entries in this row
        // now, in the new matrix
        new_m.row(v).fill(max_value); //better than using loop

    }
    /*
     * add 1 to the final vectors - preparing R output
    */
    return Rcpp::List::create(
    Rcpp::Named("dist",x),
    Rcpp::Named("parent",parent),
    Rcpp::Named("from",from+1),
    Rcpp::Named("to",to+1)
    );
}
```

In my tests, oddly only for n=50 and n=1050 valgrind show me 3 ERRORS when executing the function prim_cpp() from my prim_cpp_bug.cpp file.

Running `R -d valgrind -f cod_valgrind_test.R` from terminal returns:

> ==36904== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

The problematic lines seem to be:

- 61, 63 and 64

> ==36904== Invalid write of size 4
>   ==36904==    at 0x12315F5D: prim_cpp(arma::Mat) (prim_cpp_bug.cpp:61)

(...)

> ==36904== Invalid write of size 4
>   ==36904==    at 0x12315F63: prim_cpp(arma::Mat) (prim_cpp_bug.cpp:63)

(...)

> ==36904== Invalid write of size 4
>   ==36904==    at 0x12315F74: prim_cpp(arma::Mat) (prim_cpp_bug.cpp:64)

It seems I'm doing some wrong memory allocation for my vectors - maybe when using indices. I think I’ve read somewhere people not recommending using .at() but I'm not sure. As I don't have enough knowledge about C++ and Rcpp/RcppArmadillo to fix that, I would appreciate any help.

My sessionInfo() is below:

```
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Linux Mint 18.3

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.6.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.6.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=pt_BR.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=pt_BR.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=pt_BR.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.3 tools_3.4.3    yaml_2.1.16
```

Comment: if `parent` has `V` elements, then aren't you going out of bounds with your last iteration, where `i+1` would be `V` on line 61 (since indexing starts from 0)? The fact that it doesn't necessarily error for all cases is no surprise to me.

Comment: @RolandASc What a silly mistake! You are correct. That was the problem. Certainly, it was collecting garbage from memory in other cases. Could please answer the question so I can accept it?

Comment: @allanvc - if you accessed elements via the [regular () accessor](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#element_access) instead of `.at()`, Armadillo would have detected these out-of-bounds accesses straight away, saving you time in debugging these issues. Any particular reason you used `.at()`?  From Armadillo [docs](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#element_access): _.at(n)  or  [n] - as for (n), but without a bounds check. Not recommended for use unless your code has been **thoroughly debugged**_ (added emphasis).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `parent` is initialized with `V` elements, the indexing is going out of bounds with the last iteration, where `i+1` would be `V` on line 61 (since indexing starts from 0).

The fact that it doesn't necessarily error for all cases is not a surprise, as in many cases the code will manage to collect some random stuff from memory anyhow. So luckily there were a couple of errors, else the results could simply have been wrong without anyone noticing...

Comment: Actually, after doing some tests, the other two errors continue. I've removed the index `i+1` from  `parent.at(i+1) = v;` and moved this line (former line 61) to the beggining of the loop. The code works well for n=50 and n=1050, but when debugging with `R - d valgrind -f cod_valgrind_test.R` it is still counting two errors in its summary. Those errors are related to lines 63 and 64.

Comment: Yes, but those had the same problem with `i`, as they were initialized with `V-1` elements. Have you adjusted that as well?

Comment: I would like to say I had, but I actually had not : ) . Thanks again! Now valgrind returns 0 ERRORS.